# Inconsistent Anaconda root env after failed Python 3.5 update

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5

I recently tried to update the root environment of my Anaconda install from Python 3.4 to Python 3.5 by using the command

```
conda install python=3.5
```

After doing that, I ran

```
conda update --all python=3.5
```

hoping it would update all other packages to Python 3.5 versions, but it fails with the error message below: (note that I omitted many packages in the middle of this list)

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports_abc -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - certifi -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - colorama -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - conda -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - conda-env -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - decorator -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - django -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - ecdsa -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - flask -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - greenlet -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
  - ipykernel -> python 2.7*|3.4*

[...many more...] 

  - simplegeneric -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - six -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - werkzeug -> python 2.7*|3.4*
  - wheel -> python 2.7*|3.4*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

It seems that I've now screwed up my root environment. I'd like to just uninstall all the packages in it, but the command

```
conda uninstall --all
```

just complains:

```
Error: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again
```

(of course I cannot deactivate my environment since I'm in the root environment already.)

So, is there any way to easily clean up the root environment? Or, is there a way to correctly update all packages for Python 3.5?

## Edit (5/10/2016)

I forgot to mention originally that the system I'm running on is Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow [these steps](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) to make a clean installation:

First, remove your local anaconda: `sudo rm -rf anaconda`

Then, install it again from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: The solution proposed by Matt doesnt work. The problem here is that the new Anaconda is stricter with dependecies; hence `conda update --all` will go bananas trying to fix the dependency tree. The best is to delete everything and install it again

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: I was originally hoping for an answer that would tell me how to fix my install, rather than just reinstalling. But based on your comment and the other answers, it looks like a reinstall is the only option. Oh well!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Ms.Nehal. The essential part of the answer is already included here becasue the answer is straightforward. There are only two steps: uninstall and re-install. And for the re-install step, it is needed to download an installer file that necessarily needs to be a link

Answer (score 4):

After reading [this thread](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2180), I found this useful info:

> Conda 4.0 is a lot more careful about ensuring that environments have consistent dependencies. Previous versions of conda could actually leave environments in broken states if there were lots of one-off installs and updates.
>
> A side effect is that we're likely to see an uptick in support requests like yours, where conda is doing some surprising things as it gradually corrects broken environments.

Hence, I decided to do a clean installation that eventually solved my issues:

1. Remove conda and anaconda

   1.1 Deactivate any active environment

   `conda info --envs`

   `source deactivate`

   1.2 Manually remove the folders with the packages and code

   `sudo rm -rf anaconda/`

   `sudo rm -rf conda/`
2. Install conda and Anaconda (MiniConda)

   3.1 Download the [installer](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html) and install it following the instructions.

   3.2 Ensure correct environment variables (optional). Add this line `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH` in *.bash_profile*. Then run `source .bash_profile` so that the changes take effect. Check with `which python` and `which pip` that your python is administrated by anaconda.
3. Install your packages

   4.1 Using either `conda` or `pip` should work [source](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html)

   4.2 Update and clean up:

   `conda update --all python=3.5`

   `conda clean --all`

   4.2 Check that everything is right:

   `conda info`

   `conda list`

Answer (score 0):

Ah I am editing as I didn't know you had a mac.  Try these lines and see what happens:

`conda update conda`
`conda update conda python=3.5`
`conda update anaconda`

I realize you already ran the middle part, but others say this sequence sets the root back to 3.5.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that the system I'm running on is a Mac. (Sorry about that!) I've edited the question to reflect this information. I do also have Python 3.5-based environments, so they do work, but I was just hoping that there would be a way to upgrade the root environment without reinstalling.

Comment: @jb326 try the above.

Comment: The first two commands didn't do anything since `conda` and `python` are already at the latest versions (4.0.5 and 3.5.1, respectively). The last one fails since I don't have the `anaconda` meta-package installed. (I originally installed Miniconda instead of the full distribution.) This seems to suggest that although `python` and `conda` are good, the other packages are somehow incompatible with each other.

Comment: Ah yes I'm also running Miniconda and moved it over to the Anaconda3 directory (it still works).  You may have to do something like they did here: https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Comment: Good luck, hope you find someone w/ a Mac as I don't have one at my disposal, hope that link is helpful.